# Camel PGP- How to I decrypt with passphrase when the file is encrypted using private key

Tags: encryption, apache-camel, public-key, pgp

The file is encrypted by the customer like below

```
pgp --sign-key <Import Key> --signer <Private Key> --passphrase <Passphrase>

pgp --set-trust <Import Key> --trust complete
```

They are expecting us to decrypt like below

```
pgp --decrypt helloworld.txt.pgp --passphrase <Passphrase>
```

but it seems like in camel we cannot decrypt a file without secretKey or privateKey!

Comment: PGP don't encrypt with private key. It either encrypt with recipient's public key .. so that the recipient can decrypt with his corresponding private key. Alternatively PGP can encrypt using a passphrase. This passphrase should then also be specified on decryption.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen I understand now. Thanks

Comment: I am quite not sure how to encrypt and decrypt only with PGDataFormat of Camel-Crypto. It expects the private key for decryption!